# ActivityIndicator not spinning or animated on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

Works as expected on iOS but on Android it's just a static image. Not sure how I'm messing up something this simple!

Created a brand new project in Expo as follows:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the device you're using. I'm testing my React native app on a Samsung Galaxy S8 and a LGE G6.  On the Galaxy the ActivityIndicators animate fine, but on the LGE Phone they are static, might just be a implementation difference between brands, the image themselves are also different.